# $_POST as a function parameter

Tags: php

I've been working on a project for a game (so you'll understand that I can't post the actual script), and I'm cleaning up the code and placing code into functions instead of just after the

`if ($_POST['name'] { //code }`

Is this the correct method of doing what I'm trying? (I tried, but it broke my system)

```
if ($_POST['action'] == "actionName") actionName($_POST); //calls function if the $_POST is present
function actionName($_POST) { //code }
```

Thanks in advance for correct answers!

Comment: It's a function when it has parenthesis after it

Comment: user `'actionName'` (with ') if actionName is not a constant you defined using define(). HOW exactly did it brake your system?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$_POST is globally accessible. So you don't have to pass to your function:

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'actionName') actionName(); 

function actionName() {
    //code using $_POST
}
```

If you want your function to be able to do what it wants with any array (i.e. other than $_POST), then make the function take a parameter, but don't call it $_POST:

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'actionName') actionName($_POST); 

function actionName(parameters) {
    //code using parameters
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers! I don't have 15 reputation yet, so unfortunately I can't offer you guys upvotes. But I'd give them all ups if I could! haha Thanks again!

Comment: Decoupling code is good!

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` is a [super-global](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php). All PHP code, no matter the scope, automatically has access to this data structure.

Therefore, the following is fine:

```
if ($_POST['action'] == "actionName") {
  actionName();
}
```

and then

```
function actionName() {
  print_r($_POST);
  // code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` is already a superglobal variable so you do not need to pass it to a function. If the function needs the content of `$_POST` then make a copy and pass it to the function.

However, from your example, it seems to me that you need to pass `$_POST['action']` to your function instead of `$_POST`.

Answer (score 0):

Well in your example you need to have quotes around your string variables:

```
//calls function if the $_POST is present
if ($_POST['action'] == 'actionName') actionName($_POST); 
function actionName($_POST) { /*code*/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Although `$_POST` is super-global, yes of course you can do that and is actually a good idea. This way you decouple your code and maybe you can reuse `actionName` in another part of the application.

However, don't name the parameter of the function `$_POST` (this is more confusing than helpful).

To avoid a bunch of `if` statements for every possible action, have a look at [**`call_user_func`** *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php).

E.g. you could do:

```
$allowed_actions = array_fill_keys(array('actionName', ...), true);

if(isset($allowed_actions[$_POST['action']])) {
    call_user_func($_POST['action'], $_POST);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move the function before the code that executes it along with what everyone else here is saying about the $_POST array. Try this if you want

```
function actionName($input) { // code and return }
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    if ($action == 'actionName') {
        $name = actionName($action);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- $_POST is a super global (as other have mentioned), so you don't **need** to pass it in.
- You **can** pass it in so that you decouple the function code from the environment in which it's running. For example, should you wish to initiate such an action as a result of something else in the code, you can pass in an array with the same key/values that $_POST would have to do so
- If you do pass in $_POST to a function, name the function argument something else, hopefully something that indicates what the data represents
- Consider that the function may not need **all** the key/values that $_POST normally contains, and if you might be better off defining a function that takes only the arguments it needs in order to function

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about dynamically calling a function, you could achieve it this way:

```
/*

Example Post

$_POST['functionName'] = 'doSomething';
$_POST['value'] = 'woot!';


*/

function doSomething($message) {
    echo $message;
}


// Call the function if it exists
if (function_exists($_POST['functionName']) {

    call_user_func($_POST['functionName'], $_POST['value']);    

}


// The above would output "Woot!"
```