# Function not working

Tags: php, function, pdo

The following function is not working and i cannot see why.

```
function nuevoContacto($_POST) {
    try {
        include('func/usarBases.php');
        $mensaje="INSERT INTO `t_contactos`(`id_c`, `nombre`, `telefono`, `telefono2`, `corto`, `celular1`, `celular2`, `email`, `puesto`, `id_a`) VALUES (NULL,'$_POST[nombre]','$_POST[tel1]','$_POST[tel2]','$_POST[corto]','$_POST[cel1]','$_POST[cel2]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[puesto]','$_POST[id_a]')";
        $hacerConsulta = $base->prepare($mensaje);
        $hacerConsulta->execute();
    }
    catch( PDOException $e) {
        echo "<p>Error Connection: " .$e->getMessage()."</p>";
    }   
    $hacerConsulta=null;
}
```

Once it is called the code breaks and nothing further is executed.
but when you use it inside the main code it works

Sorry i reedited the source and then is still not working, in the include usarBases.php is the conector pdo called $base

Comment: You'll need to define `$base` inside your function. As well as `$instruccion`.

Comment: My eyes ache when I see such a code

Comment: For future reference, you should also give information about what error you get rather than just saying "it breaks"

Comment: that sql is just asking to get something injected

Comment: `$_POST` is a superglobal. you should **NOT** not be naming a function parameter with that name.

Comment: Consider the following http://stackoverflow.com/a/6558736/1415724 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660912/passing-post-array-to-php-function which outlines what `Marc B` mentioned above.

Comment: @MarcB That's what I thought as well.

Comment: Sorry for this code, but i'm self learning to do. this is the first time i ask for help in a year of learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're lacking a database connection in your function. Add the following to the very beginning of your function:

```
global $base;
```

When you add `global $base` to your function you'll be able to use it within your function without having to re-write the whole thing.

Unrelated note, but worth mentioning.

You are **open to SQL injections** and you're not using prepared statements as you should. You should be using placeholders and [binding](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) them later instead of passing they directly into your query.

And a tip for next time:
State in your question **what** isn't working. What your expectation is and what actually happens.

Comment: Whoever downvoted my answer, explain why if you would.

Comment: It wasn't me, but I'm guessing it was because you used `global`, instead of passing it through the function.

Comment: @BenFortune Is using `global` considered back practice or something?

Comment: From what I've seen, SO hates `global`. :P

Comment: @BenFortune [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/php-global-in-functions#5166527) makes a good point. I can now see why my answer got downvoted.

Comment: Sorry for this code, but i'm self learning to do. this is the first time i ask for help in a year of learning

Comment: @CesarPeña I'd recommend you to take Your Common Sense's approach to be honest.

Answer (score 2):

What it have to be

```
function nuevoContacto($base)
{
    $sql  = "INSERT INTO  t_contactos VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    $data = array(
        $_POST['nombre'],
        $_POST['tel1'],
        $_POST['tel2'],
        $_POST['corto'],
        $_POST['cel1'],
        $_POST['cel2'],
        $_POST['email'],
        $_POST['puesto'],
        $_POST['id_a']
    );
    $stmt = $base->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($data);
}
```

have to be called with $base as a parameter instead of $_POST